# How to obtain restricted page URL when anon

Tags: apostrophe-cms

The title says it all: in the site which we are currently building, we have pages that have permissions for admin, guest, and anon.

One of the widgets we created allow for an admin to select *any* page, and then it generates a link in the page. With [apostrophe-second-chance-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apostrophe-second-chance-login), this should work fine.

```
[...]
{
  label: 'Page, article, product, etc.',
  help: 'Content to which the button leads',
  name: '_target',
  type: 'joinByOne',
  withType: LinkableTypes,
  filters: {
    projection: {
      _url: 1
    }
  },
  idField: 'id'
}
[...]
```

`LinkableTypes` is just an array of the widget names to which the link can lead:

```
[
  "apostrophe-page",
  "article",
  "machine",
  "engine",
  "accessory"
]
```

`apostrophe-page` is obvious, the other ones are pieces.

We run into an issue where the widget in anon mode will not obtain any value for `data.widget._target._url`.

We started to look into overriding the `load` method in the `construct`

```
construct(self, options) {
  const superLoad = self.load;
    self.load = (req, widgets, callback) => {
    superLoad(self.apos.tasks.getReq(), widgets, callback)
  };
}
```

but it seems like it doesn't work in all contexts. In the language that is not the default, `data.widget._target._url` is null, while proper in the default language. We use [apostrophe-workflow](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-workflow/).

I am trying to avoid creating components which would have the URL hardcoded in them.

Comment: I would expect your original join not to return pages the user does not have permission to see at all, not just leaving out _url in the response. However, try adding permission: false to your "filters" section of the join. This should fetch all of the results regardless of permissions.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, thanks so much @TomBoutell !

Comment: Great, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `permission: false` to the `filters` section of your join, pages will be returned without regard to permissions. You should use this judiciously, but it allows you to create the links to pages a logged-in user can't immediately see that you are looking for.